# Split a string in Java and insert it into an empty string

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
20210903|0000000001|0081|A|T60|BSN|002|STATE UNITED
```

I have imported this file in my java application with this code:

```
public List<EquivalenceGroupsTO> read() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/myself/Desk/blaBla/T60.csv"))) {

        List<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        Integer count = 0;
        HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();

        while (line != null) {
            //System.out.println("data <" + count + "> :" + line);
            count++;
            file.add(line);
            file.add("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        EquivalenceGroupsTO equivalenceGroupsTO = new EquivalenceGroupsTO();

        List<EquivalenceGroupsTO> equivalenceGroupsTOs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String row : file) {
            equivalenceGroupsTO = new EquivalenceGroupsTO();
            String[] str = row.split("|");
            equivalenceGroupsTO.setEquivalenceGroupsCode(str[5]);
            equivalenceGroupsTO.setDescription(str[7]);
            equivalenceGroupsTO.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
            equivalenceGroupsTOs.add(equivalenceGroupsTO);
            System.out.println("Tutto ok!");
        }
        return equivalenceGroupsTOs;
    }
}
```

I need to set in the **equivalenceGroupsTO.setEquivalenceGroupsCode** and in the **equivalenceGroupsTO.setDecription** (which are strings) respectively the strings after the fifth and the seventh "|" , then "**BSN**" and "**STATE UNITED**".

But if I start this script it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 1
at it.utils.my2.read(OpenTXTCodifa.java:46)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want: `String[] str = row.split("\\|");`

Comment: Do some basic debugging. The "|" is a special character for a regex. I wrote a simple single line test code to demonstrate this: `System.out.println( "1|2|3".split("|").length );` and it displayed "5". Using the above suggestion to escape the "|" I got "3" which is correct. So given that your code thinks you only have a single value in the array you have some other issue as well. Why would you add the "\n" back into your ArrayList? Why do you even have an ArrayList? Just process each line of text as you read it from the file.

Comment: As people have said above, the vast majority of that code is redundant. Create your *List<EquivalenceGroupsTO> equivalenceGroupsTOs = new ArrayList<>();* and split on `"\\|"` and add to that `List` in the loop then return it

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is mentioned in the comments: when splitting by `|` character, it has to be escaped as `\\|` because the pipe character is user as OR operator in the regular espressions.

Next issue is adding a line containing only `\n` to `file`.  When this line is split, `str[5]` will fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Other minor issues are unused variables `count` and `hset`.

However, it may be better to refactor existing code to use NIO and Stream API to get a stream of lines and convert each line into corresponding list of `EquivalenceGroupsTO`:

```java
public List<EquivalenceGroupsTO> read(String filename) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)) // Stream<String>
            .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))       // Stream<String[]>
             // make sure all data are available
            .filter(arr -> arr.length > 7)  // Stream<String[]>
            .map(arr -> {
                EquivalenceGroupsTO egTo = new EquivalenceGroupsTO();
                egTo.setEquivalenceGroupsCode(str[5]);
                egTo.setDescription(str[7]);
                egTo.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
                return egTo;
            }) // Stream<EquivalenceGroupsTO>
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```